# Test SqlAlchemy column type

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When you have your table columns type, how to test if they are of a particular type?

```
types = {c.name: c.type for c in table.columns}
for col_name, type_ in types.items():
        print(col_name, type(type_), isinstance(VARCHAR, type(type_)), isinstance(type(type_), VARCHAR))
```

It always return lines like:

```
REGION <class 'sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.types.VARCHAR'> False False
```

What is the correct method to test column type?

Answer (score 2):

To test the type you have to use issubclass instead of isinstance:

```
issubclass(type(type_), VARCHAR))
```